# How to create horizontal scrolling chart in d3

Tags: html, d3.js

When I creating a gantt chart my time scale is high and small tasks are not properly visible so I want to scroll horizontally so I can view my chart properly anyone please help?

Comment: please provide more details how you create the gantt chart

Comment: not sure what your code looks like, but if you put it in a div with a css property of overflow-x: scroll; it might work

Comment: Seems like a good time for panning: http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434